# dataLayer.push eccomerce not appearing in GTM data Layer

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am testing setting up purchase tracking to send a data layer of purchase info to GTM. The data layer is correctly grabbing the info but for some reason I am not seeing anything when I preview GTM. As you can see in this image here I do not get the purchase event in GTM which is what my GA4 tag is set to fire on or any info from the data layer.  [empty GTM data-layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBYSU.png)

Does anyone know why this is not working correctly?

```
<script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

        dataLayer.push({ 'ecommerce': null });
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'purchase',
            'ecommerce': {
                'purchase': {
                    'actionField': {
                        'id': xxxxxxx,
                        'affiliation': ,
                        'revenue': 40,
                        'tax': ,
                        'shipping': ,
                    },
                    'products': [
                                                {
                            'id': xx-xx,
                            'name': xxxxxxx,
                            'category': xxxxxxx,
                            'price': 40,
                            'quantity': 1                        },
                                            ]
                }
            },
            'user_data': {
                'email': test@gmail.com,
                'phone_number': 7777777777,
                'address': {
                    'first_name': Test,
                    'last_name': Test,
                    'street': 123 test st,
                    'city': test23,
                    'region': WV,
                    'postal_code': 12345,,
                'country': US,,
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Please add: screenshots of your set up in gtm, screenshots of the dataLayer object from the console, screenshots of the dataLayer state on different events.

Comment: The javascript looks like there are some problems. Like the address.postal_code 12345,, . You have two commas which might not be valid javascript. Please check the javascript is running correctly.